# Slim Framework 3 - Response object

Tags: php, slim-3

In my Slim 3 application I have defined a middleware that adds a custom header to my response. The middleware is called **before** index routing function is called. If an exception is thrown, the error handler function is called, but it seems the $response object passed to that function is a new Response object and not the one customized in my middleware. In other words, in my response I don't have my custom header.

Is this behaviour correct?

```
# Middleware
$app->add(function ($request, $response, $next) {
  $response = $response->withHeader('MyCustomHeader', 'MyCustomValue');
  return $next($request, $response);
});

# Error handling
$container['errorHandler'] = function ($container) {
  return function ($request, $response, $exception) use ($container) {
    return $response->write('ERROR');
  };
};

# Index
$app->get('/index', function(Request $request, Response $response) {
  throw new exception();
  return $response->write('OK');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Yes, its correct, because:*

The `Request` and `Response` objects are immutable, therefore they need to be passed through all the functions. When throwing an exception this chain is broken and the newly created Response object (on `withHeader`-method) cannot get passed to the errorHandler.

You can fix that problem by throwing a `\Slim\Exception\SlimException`, this exception takes 2 parameter. The request and response. With this Slim uses the request and response given in the exception inside the error handler.

```
$app->get('/index', function(Request $request, Response $response) {
    throw new \Slim\Exception\SlimException($request, $response);
    return $response->write('OK');
});
```